# Toggle divs and add class active to them

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have an example here where there are some random divs and when a button linked to them is clicked, i want a tooltip to toggle 9hide/show) which i can easily do- but here are my problems:

http://jsfiddle.net/KcLTw/1/

1) When you click onto another button the other tooltip doesnt hide so i am getting to toggle on and off but not toggling off when click on another button.

2)Previously, when i had the one toggling, i could toggle the class now with my updated code this is not the case and seems to ignore it.

3) With the example i have is there another way instead of having:

```
<input type="button" id="" class="buttons" value="tooltip1"></input>
```

To have a div but where i am stuck is where to pull the value bit in from my jQuery as divs dont have the value state like on form elements?

```
var div= $("#"+this.value);
```

Sorry if this seems a bit silly, i am new to jQuery and learning as i go along. Any guidance would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jquery code :

```
$(".buttons").click(function () {
    tooltip = "#"+$(this).val();
    $('.tooltip').not(tooltip).hide()

    if ($(tooltip).is(":visible")) {
        $(tooltip).hide().removeClass("selected")
    } else {
        $(tooltip).show().addClass("selected")
    }
});
```

and have a look to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KcLTw/3/).

Comment: Thats great thank you. I've just looked at my code and it seems that with using buttons, (rather use divs) but for instance what happens if my buttons have like 1,2,3 and other ones further down have different names? Basically its like house numbers and then 1a 2b 2c, how would these toggle as they value inside is going to be different. Here is a link for example: http://jsfiddle.net/KcLTw/4/

Comment: If you change their valeur, the won't work. But, you can use an alternative. Look this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KcLTw/5/. If you updated the jquery code and the input and div ID.

Comment: And my answer could help you, you can validate it.

Comment: This is fantastic, just so i understand, does the slice skip the letters in the div to retrieve the val? Also dont think i explained my issue properly, the buttons are the ones to toggle the active state not the tooltips themselves :). This is great code +1

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, just add this second line of code (the first is from your code as reference as where to add it):

```
var tooltip= $("#"+this.value);
$(".tooltip").hide();
```

Comment: That seems great but now when you click on them again to hide they dont? Nearly there!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(".buttons").click(function () {

    var tooltip= $("#"+this.value);        
    var isVisible = tooltip.is(":visible");
    $('.tooltip').hide();
    if (isVisible) {
        tooltip.hide();
    } else {
        tooltip.show();
    }

    if ($('.tooltip').is(":visible")) {
        $('?').addClass("selected"); 
    } else {
        $('?').removeClass("selected"); 
    }

});
```

This way you close all `tooltip divs` and toggle `div` that is related to the `button`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
    $(".buttons").click(function () {
      var button = $(this);
      var buttons = $(".buttons");
      var tooltip = $("#"+this.value);

      if(button.hasClass("active")){
        $(".tooltip").hide();
        buttons.removeClass("active");
      }else {
        buttons.removeClass("active");
        $(".tooltip").hide();                    
        tooltip.toggle();
        button.addClass("active");
      }
 });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akbar_pk/jbPXw/2/)